# WebView not working, launching the url externally in browser. Displaying webpage inside app

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-intent, webview

I made a home or main activity which has some icons and one of them is facebook, and by clicking it a facebook.xml is launched via intent

The code for that xml page is set as below:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
android:id="@+id/webView" >
</WebView>
```

And I want to load the url: "http://www.j.mp/tkf4mApp"

The Java file which is linked to this xml file is as below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Facebook extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebookpage);

    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.j.mp/tkf4mApp");


}
}
```

But instead of showing webpage inside the app in facebook.xml it launches browser externally, but i want it to be shown inside the app.

Comment: this will be showing webview inside your app only

Comment: It seems correct, to me.

Comment: Its launching external options, like to choose in between opera, uc browser, native browser and chrome (Which are in my phone), the app canbe accessed by the following url :http://j.mp/thekfac

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per this answer: [How to load external webpage inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview?rq=1) you need to set a WebViewClient before you call `loadUrl`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

The reason you're being sent to the browser is that if no WebViewClient is set then the default action for navigations is to forward them to the browser.

Comment: I tried that but that too is not working,please help if there is some other way.  the app canbe accessed by the following url :j.mp/thekfac

Comment: @MananGupta you linked your APK. That doesn't make it any simpler to investigate. Also, what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Okay, i attached just to lt you see. And not working means it doesn't happen to bring change in the app. App is working same as before, i added that line and recompiled, it is launching the site to external browser. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @MananGupta - try doing this:

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         android.util.Log.w("Test", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading " + url);
         return false;
      }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.j.mp/tkf4mApp");

and check that you see the debug message in the log.

Comment: thanks buddy, just doing it, i'll leave a reply ASAP

Comment: thanks it works fine man, but like when i click on icon it open that xml which is blank, it is shown until the page is loaded.Is there a way i can show a loading icon or something that gives user a idea that it is loading. Please help me out with this thing. So i can show a loading icon or image until webpage completely appears.

Comment: @MananGupta - you could start showing the loading icon in WebViewClient.onPageStarted (or shouldOverrideUrlLoading even) and hide it in WebViewClient.onPageFinished.

Comment: Will you please elaborate more, it will be more than grateful

Comment: yes, it worked well....working by calling webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); even after calling loadUrl :)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   private WebView browser;

   @Override        
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
   }


   public void open(View view){
      String url = "http://www.j.mp/tkf4mApp";
      browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      browser.loadUrl(url);

   }
   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

This Link may Help You...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following project, this one works

https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

Answer (score 0):

This is late but it might help other developers....

Here is the code that you need to add before loading your URL.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As per the documentation, documentational words goes like below

```
/*@return {@code true} if the host application wants to leave the current WebView
             *         and handle the url itself, otherwise return {@code false}.*/
```

So it simply says, If you return **true** from **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method, it'll ask the default browser of your device to handle the request of opening the URL and if you return **false**, then your URL will be loaded through webview only.

Now you can load your URL in **webview** either after this **setWebViewClient** call or you can also load your URL inside **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method before returning the value.