# Best way to check internet connection in background?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connection, background-process

I want to check the internet connection, not only if the user is connected to a network, I want to check that this network actually is connected to the internet, im using the following code:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 

            if (ipAddr.equals("")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Got it from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7305089/3290977) thanks by the way.

This is not working as I would liko to, always return false even if Im in a correct network,I would like to know how to run this in the background and show a progress indicator which tells the user the progress of the conection test.

I need help with this cause my app works 80% with JSON parse and I rather prefer to check the connection once at the begginnign instead of checking every time I parse a JSON. Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection) thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,

I would use progress bar (javaFX) and use a single thread which runs your function and updates the progress bar correspondingly

[ProgressBar and Background Processes](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/ProgressBarandBackgroundProcesses.htm)

[Android:Using Thread and Progress bar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingThreadandProgressbar.htm)

Comment: Well I forgot to say java maybe?