# Android Webview shows loader and none of webview methods gets called

Tags: android, webview

I'm facing a strange issue in my app. I'm using webview in detail pages. When I open the detail pages, web view loads the web page. But sometimes, webview doesn't load and just shows a loader. On Debugging call goes to `loadUr()`, but after that none of the webview methods are called. and after this all web pages goes blank with a loader. I'm not getting the callback to `onRecieveError()` too. I'm really not getting what is causing this issue.

I tried with all these things:
`

```
   vWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`;

        vWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        vWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

 vWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override

}
if (mContentUrl != null) {
            vWebView.clearCache(true);
            vWebView.loadUrl(mContentUrl);
        }
```

It's happening randomly. And when I switch off and on the wifi, it starts loading the pages normally. I'm not getting what is creating the problem. Because other native sections are downloading the stream and there is no connectivity issue. Only this webview, behaving strangly sometimes

Comment: Your code seems fine (although are you sure you want to clear cache each time?) In any event, try the code in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7306176/834692

Comment: Earlier I was not clearing the cache. In one post, suggested that, we should clear cache, but even that doesn't work for me.