# Implementing WebView with help of Firebase in Android

Tags: android, url, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

I am using **webView** in my application and also using **Firebase as a database**, I have implemented the database for images and text in Firebase database for **real time** retrieval but the problem I am facing now is that I want to **load a URL in Firebase database** and gets shown on **webView in my app**, I cant make it work and have researched many questions and blogs but did not found anything useful to me, please help

> I am using Android Studio and Firebase

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to load an image in your webview which its URL is stored in a database? Well why don't you use a ImageView? I've always used Picasso with ImageViews and never had any problems.
Here is an example:
http://square.github.io/picasso/
I hope it helped you out.

Comment: no sir, i want to load a web page in my webView, dont know how to do it with firebase

Comment: If you to load an existing webpage in your WebView just use: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38505589/5724149

Comment: Yes sir but that will put static URL, what i want is to put URL on database and then get it from it to webView so that if i have to change the URL i can

Comment: Do you want to store the URL that you loaded inside your webview to be saved inside the database?

Comment: Yes sir, and also i want that if i want to change it, i can do it from database so that new webpage is shown at the place of previous

Comment: The storing is not the hardest part? Just getting the url from the webview by using `String webUrl = webView.getUrl();`, You have to create a listener that checks the database every x (mili)seconds, but that causes a lot of traffic, so it isn't ideal.