# HOW SHOW DIFFERENT TEXT COLOR?

Tags: android, textview

I have one problem to show text with different color word then I search it and find this page

[Change text color of one word in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221930/change-text-color-of-one-word-in-a-textview)

and this page

[Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-font-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview)

and this page

[How to load external webpage inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview)

there answer does not solve my problem because I have very long text to colored it and also I want text like that image

[image]

and this code for one word like image not work

```
final SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
final int flag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;

//converting arabic text to unicode chars
String dd= "بِسْمِ" ;
ssb.append(dd);
//applying colors
ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 1, 2, flag);
ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3, 4, flag);
ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 5, 6, flag);
//seting formated spanned text
TextView mTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  mTextView.setText(ssb);
```

Please answer this question with simple code

Comment: Is my question ok now?

Comment: I want my question is validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Spannable:

```
SpannableStringBuilder mySpanText= new SpannableStringBuilder("Some long sentence");
```

Define text color for a piece of string(i.e. the word "long"):

```
mySpanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                0, mySpanText.length(), 0 );
```

Assign the text value to your TextView:

```
TextView myTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_tv);

myTextView .setText(mySpanText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

For more ways and for documentation, look in the links below:

- Android studio reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html
- Spannable tutorial: http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2012/03/single-textview-with-multiple-action.html

Comment: Hi Scott! Please do not use blockquote formatting for things that are not actually quotations. Plain text works just fine here, since the code blocks provide enough separation. If you need separation between blocks of text, you might use a horizontal line (`----`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Cody.

Comment: thanks for Guide me /////  I am searching and found a lot of tutorial about Spannable