# Webpage is not loading correctly on In-App browser Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-chrome-app

I am working on a project which requires opening another Web app in app browser. For that, I used WebView inside Activity and simply loads the Web App URL into it. But it is not rendering the page as it renders in Chrome browser.
I have searched for that and updated some WebView setting in Activity but still no luck.
Following are the settings:
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

```
    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Do I need to add more settings apart from that? Any leads will be appreciable.

Comment: check this question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview

Comment: mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); should be enough, maybe your WebView has other Visibility state than VISIBLE ? maybe you don't have permission Internet in Manifest?

Comment: @b2mob The app has all the permission required, the Web page is getting rendered but some of the parts of it is not rendering correctly.

Comment: @Profreak can you post the url? Maybe it's mobile page version has some errors?

Comment: There is no error in page as it is rendering correctly in mobile chrome browser.

Comment: @Profreak are you fix it ? i am also facing this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using [viewport properties](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Viewport).

You can enable wide viewport mode with [`setUseWideViewPort()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)).

> You can define properties of the viewport for your web page, such as the width and initial zoom level, using the `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag in your document `<head>`.

Check this [tutorial](https://www.androidauthority.com/working-with-webview-736873/) for additional insights.